# How to program a video calling application in Vaadin 14

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm new to Vaadin. I want to create an application that will allow a user to make video calls from an Android device to a Desktop/Laptop. I tried searching for examples on YouTube but could not find anything. i want to implement this on Vaadin 14 spring boot and java project. Please help with an example to do this kind of project.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite wide topic and in the borderline can it be answered according to StackOverflow policies.

My general advice is to study WebRTC for peer to peer communications. I would recommend to use the application only as a broker of the connection. I have seen proof of concept demo made about this on Vaadin 8.

Vaadin framework itself does not provide official WebRTC using components, libraries at the moment. However there was add-on made for earlier Vaadin 8. It is using 3rd party JavaScript library. Just noting, that there are couple of libraries to choose from.

https://vaadin.com/directory/component/webrtc-add-on